# Datetime.strftime() not modifying properly?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, datetime

I'm trying to change the datetime objects in a list-of-lists to strings using strftime, but the conversion to string is acting confusingly. Specifically, I'm trying to format it as %H:%M

I've parsed an Excel file with Pandas and converted the DataFrame into a list-of-lists using NumPy.

Here's the relevant section(s) of my code

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import time

... 

dataframe = pd.read_excel(download_file, skiprows=4)
location_logs = dataframe.to_numpy().tolist()

for log in location_logs:
    for val in log:
        if type(val) == datetime.datetime:
            val = val.strftime("%H:%M")
```

The loop is identifying datetime objects correctly as a print statement inside the conditional matches the data and even prints the formatted string instead of the datetime object.

However, if I print a list such as `location_logs[0]`, it prints the datetime object found in the nested list instead of the string, i.e., printing `datetime.datetime(2019,6,17,23,59)` instead of my expected `23:59`

Am I going about converting datetime objects incorrectly? Is it possible the size of the list-of-lists is causing an issue? There are ~62k lists with 7 elements in each list.

Comment: You need to `enumerate` your loop and replace the values at each index. `val = val.strftime("%H:%M")` is an assignment and has no link at all to the items actually in the list

Comment: If the dates are all in one column, you can just do `df["date_col"].dt.strftime("%H:%M")` instead of looping. Looping in pandas is generally quite inefficient. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: Mmm, I'm tempted to roll back my edit. The question, as is, doesn't really involve them and is a fundamental python issue. But the problem could  better fixed within pandas I guess

Comment: `for val in log:` - `val` is not a pointer to the element in `log`, it is a copy. So altering it has no effect on `log`. I would suggest that rather than trying to change the collection you are iterating over, create a copy and make the changes in the copy.

Comment: All of the dates are in a single column, yes. The enumeration worked - I will try the Pandas solution as well, many thanks! @Dan if you want to make your explanation an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: You are just assigning the strings to a variable and then doing nothing with it. The list and its items are the same as before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like:

```
location_logs = [datetime.datetime(2009, 9, 12, 11, 23, 44), datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 10, 6, 21, 15)]

for i in range(len(location_logs)):
    if type(location_logs[i]) == datetime.datetime:
        location_logs[i] = location_logs[i].strftime("%H:%M")

location_logs
```

Result:

```
['11:23', '06:21']
```